An example with disintegration as in Rokhlin disintegration theorem .
Here is the statement of Rokhlin disintegration theorem I am using:
Let $X,Y$ be compact metric spaces with Borel sigma algebras $B$ and $A,$ respectively. Let $T: X \to Y$ be a continuous map. Let $\mu$ be the probability measure on $X$ and let $\nu = T_* \mu$ be its pushforward to $Y.$ Show that for almost every $y \in Y$ there is a probability measure $\nu_y$ on $X$ supported on $T^{-1}(y),$ with the property that for any map $f \in L^1(X, B, \mu),$ we have $$\int_X f d\mu = \int_{Y}\Big( \int_{T^{-1}(y)}f d\nu_{y} \Big) d \nu(y).$$
In other words, we have the function $F(y) = \int_{T^{-1}(y)} f d\nu_y,$ and then $\int_X f d\mu = \int_Y F d\nu.$
I am trying to find an example with disintegration as mentioned in the theorem above.
More specifically, Assuming that $T: [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ is the projection onto the first factor. And, for each measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]^2,$ let $\nu$ denote its push-forward. For each $x \in [0,1],$ find the measure $\nu_y$ as in the previous post in the following cases:
$(1)$ $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.
$(2)$ $\mu = f(x,y) dx\,dy$ for some measurable function $f.$
I am not sure how to find these examples.
Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

For the first part,

$\mu$ is the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure on the square $[0,1]^2$.
$\nu$ is the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure on the interval $[0,1]$.
For $x\in[0,1]$, the fiber $T^{-1}(x)=\{x\}\times [0,1]$ is the vertical line segment in the square above the point $x$.
For $x\in[0,1]$, the fiber measure $\nu_x$ is the measure supported on the fiber $T^{-1}(x)$. Recall that by Fubini Theorem the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure can be evaluated using two iterated integrals, hence $\nu_x$ is equal to the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $T^{-1}(x)=\{x\}\times [0,1]$. More specifically, for $\phi:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto \phi(x,y)$ measurable, one has for $\nu$-almost every $x\in [0,1]$,

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\nu_x}(\phi) = \int_{\{x\}\times[0,1]}\phi\, d\nu_x = \int_0^1\phi(x,y)\,dy.
$$
Consequently, disintegration gives in this case the standard Fubini:
$$
\int_{[0,1]^2}\phi(x,y)\, d\mu(x,y) = \int_0^1 \,\left(\int_0^1 \phi(x,y)\, dy\right)\,dx.
$$

For the second part,

$\mu$ now is a measure absolutely continuous relative to the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure, say

$$
\mu(A) = \int_A \rho(x,y) dydx
$$
(Here $\rho$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ relative to the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure.)

$\nu$ is the pushforward measure on the interval $[0,1]$. To identify a form for it, let $\psi:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function.

\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]}\psi(x)d\nu(x)
&=\int_{[0,1]^2}\psi\circ T(x,y) d\mu(x,y)\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{T^{-1}(x)} \psi\circ T(x,y) \rho(x,y) \,dy\right)\, dx\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_0^1 \psi(x) \rho(x,y) \,dy\right)\, dx\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\psi(x)\,\, \underbrace{\left(\int_0^1  \rho(x,y) \,dy\right)}_{=\xi(x)}\,\, dx\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\psi(x)\xi(x)\, dx
\end{align*}
Consequently $\nu$ is absolutely continuous relative to the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative is
$$
\xi(x)=\int_0^1  \rho(x,y) \,dy.
$$

Finally to identify a form for the fiberwise measures, let $\phi:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be measurable. We'll write the expectation of $\phi$ relative to $\mu$ as an iterated integral, where the outer integral is relative to the pushforward measure $\nu$:

\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]^2} \phi(x,y) d\mu(x,y)
&= \int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{[0,1]} \phi(x,y)\rho(x,y)\, dy\right)\, dx\\
&= \int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{T^{-1}(x)} \phi(x,y)\dfrac{\rho(x,y)}{\xi(x)}\, dy\right)\, \xi(x)dx\\
&= \int_{[0,1]}\left(\int_{T^{-1}(x)} \phi(x,y)\dfrac{\rho(x,y)}{\xi(x)}\, dy\right)\, d\nu(x)
\end{align*}
Thus for $\nu$-ae $x\in [0,1]$, one has that the fiber measure $\nu_x$ is absolutely continuous relative to the vertical one-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\{x\}\times [0,1]$ and the Radon-Nikodym derivative is
$$
y\mapsto\dfrac{\rho(x,y)}{\xi(x)} = \dfrac{\rho(x,y)}{\int_0^1 \rho(x,z) dz}.
$$
